# include second cmake project in main project

Tags: cmake

I have a directory layout like the following

```
projectA/
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- src/
    |-- main.cpp
projectB/
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- src/
    |-- file1.cpp
    |-- file1.hpp
    |-- file2.hpp
    |-- main.cpp
|-- third_party/
    |-- include
        |-- lib1
```

I can build my code (separately) for `projectA` and `projectB` just fine, i.e. both projects run by itself, independet of each other.

Now, in `projectA` I need to use code that exists in `projectB` (specifically `file1.cpp`, `file1.hpp`, `file2.hpp` and the third party libs).

It seems bad practice to me to just copy the necessary files from `projectB/src`, paste it into the `src` directory of `projectA` and adjust the `CMakeLists.txt` in `projectA` accordingly (by partially merging `projectB/CMakeLists.txt` and `projectA/CMakeLists.txt`).

Is there a nice way I can use CMake to (and now I'm not sure about the right terminology) include the project defined by `projectB/CMakeLists.txt` in `projectA/CMakeLists.txt`. The idea is that everything concerning `projectB` to run independently is stated in `projectB/CMakeLists.txt` and shouldn't I be able to access this information when I want to use it in `projectA`?

This is probably a common question, nevertheless I did not find anything helpful online, might also be due to not having the right terminology at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide the level of encapsulation you need.

1. **Package:** If dependency ProjectB can run independently and you only ever need it for its compiled library, then use CMake's packaging system, i.e. `export(TARGETS)` or `export(EXPORT)` or `export(PACKAGE)` or `install(EXPORT)`.
2. **add_subdirectory**: If dependency ProjectB also has build target information you need, e.g. compile defines, flags and other dependencies, then you can just make a top-level CMakeLists and use `add_subdirectory()`
3. **include:** If dependency ProjectB only has sub-target properties you need, including sources, you could `include()` the `CMakeLists.txt`, but this is really designed for sub directories and where you do not want to change the existing current directory for CMake processing
4. **Interface library**: If your third party libraries are not header-only, then they should probably be independent packages, otherwise assuming they are not huge like Boost, you can just copy them to ProjectA. Boost-like dependencies should almost always be kept external to projects
5. **Hardcode paths**: You could hardcode paths to the individual files of projectB, but this is brittle without making it a subdirectory of projectA, which in turn would offer better solutions, as above
6. **Refactor to third library:** If none of the above fits, you could refactor out the specific files as a separate library and use the standard packaging mechanism to depend on it for both ProjectA and ProjectB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ExternalProject` module
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html

Suppose, projectB is library. Then:

```
project("A")
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(b_lib
      SOURCE_DIR "${B_SOURCE_DIR}" 
      BINARY_DIR "${B_BUILD_DIR}"
      CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
                 "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${B_INSTALL_DIR}" 
                 "-DARBITRARY_VAR=some_value")

add_executable(a_exe src/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(a_exe PRIVATE "${B_INSTALL_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(a_exe "${B_INSTALL_DIR}/b_lib")
```